# Why do these different methods of assigning an array/list result in different values?

Tags: arrays, perl

```
@rt = (10,9,8);
my ($x)=@rt;
$y = @rt;
$z = (10,9,8);
print "\$x=$x,\$y=$y,\$z=$z\n";
```

output:
$x=10,$y=3,$z=8

Why the values of $x,$y,$z are different?
Why $z value is not equal to size of @rt?

```
$x = $rt[0]
$y = Scalar(@rt)
$z = $rt[2]
```

Why little difference in assigning array to scalar have different values? This make me think Perl is tedious or one need to careful while coding. Please comment on it.

Comment: Because it's perl .. and the 3 forms are different. This part is answer-worthy. The request to "comment on" perl being tedious or requiring more care, however, is *not* a good addition to the first question.

Comment: "array" is a variable type, not a value type.  values are scalars or lists.

Comment: Almost all programming languages require one to be careful when coding.

Answer (score 9):

Perl has two different assignment operators, a scalar assignment operator and a list assignment operator.  Which an assignment is, is based syntactically on what appears on the left; if that is an array, a hash, a slice, or a parenthesized expression it is a list assignment; otherwise it is a scalar assignment.  List assignments give their right operand list context; scalar assignments give their right operand scalar context.

Taking them one at a time:

```
@rt = (10,9,8);
```

List assignment.  The right operand gets list context.  The comma operator in list context assembles a list, which is then assigned into the array.

```
my ($x) = @rt;
```

List assignment.  The right operand gets list context; an array in list context produces a list of its elements, which are assigned into the list that is the list assignments left operand.  Because that list has only one scalar element, only the first element of the array ends up being assigned and the remaining elements of the list produced from the array are discarded.

```
$y = @rt;
```

Scalar assignment.  The right operand gets scalar context; an array in scalar context produces its length, which is assigned to the variable on the left of the assignment.

```
$z = (10,9,8);
```

Scalar assignment.  The right operand gets scalar context.  The comma operator in scalar context throws away its left operand and returns only its right operand, so the value of the left operand of the assignment is just the number 8, which is assigned into the variable on the left of the assignment.

Answer (score 2):

Variable list on the left side (list context) and a list on the right side, assigns corresponding items. The first, and the only, item on the left hand side gets the first item from the list:

```
my ($x)=@rt;  # x = rt[0]
```

Scalar on the left side, list on the right side. List is evaluated in a scalar context, transforms into its length:

```
$y = @rt;  # y = size of rt
```

the last one is the [comma operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Comma-Operator), in scalar context it evaluates to the last item on the right side.

```
$z = (10,9,8); # z = 8;
```